# Not able to perform any event after image click?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs

This is my code which is getting dynamically appended by a plugin

```
<div class="emoji-menu" style="top: 913px; left: 1211.5px; display: block;">
  <div class="emoji-items-wrap1">
    <div class="emoji-items-wrap nano mobile_scrollable_wrap has-scrollbar">
      <div class="emoji-items nano-content" tabindex="-1" style="right: -17px;">                
        <a href="javascript:void(0)" title=":unamused:">
          <img src="img/blank.gif" class="img" style="display:inline-block;width:20px;height:20px;background:url('img/emojisprite_0.png') -360px 0px no-repeat;background-size:540px 140px;" alt=":unamused:">
          <span class="label">:unamused:</span>
        </a>
        <a href="javascript:void(0)" title=":joy:">
          <img src="img/blank.gif" class="img" style="display:inline-block;width:20px;height:20px;background:url('img/emojisprite_0.png') -440px 0px no-repeat;background-size:540px 140px;" alt=":joy:">
          <span class="label">:joy:</span>
        </a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

The problem is that i need to change .emoji-menu's div property to display:none whenever the img tag inside it gets clicked(please refer the code), I have tried with different selectors but it didn't work.

I think `<a href="javascript:void(0)"` is causing problem. Please help me on this.

Answer (score 0):

With angular you can use ngClick and ngShow for these things:

```
<div ng-show="thisEmoji" class="emoji-menu" style="top: 913px; left: 1211.5px; display: block;">
  <div class="emoji-items-wrap1">
    <div class="emoji-items-wrap nano mobile_scrollable_wrap has-scrollbar">
      <div class="emoji-items nano-content" tabindex="-1" style="right: -17px;">
        <img ng-click="thisEmoji = true" src="img/blank.gif" class="img" style="display:inline-block;width:20px;height:20px;background:url('img/emojisprite_0.png') -360px 0px no-repeat;background-size:540px 140px;" alt=":unamused:">
        <span class="label">:unamused:</span>
        <img ng-click="thisEmoji = true" src="img/blank.gif" class="img" style="display:inline-block;width:20px;height:20px;background:url('img/emojisprite_0.png') -440px 0px no-repeat;background-size:540px 140px;" alt=":joy:">
        <span class="label">:joy:</span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

The a tag could be replaced with removed as it only ads a title to the element. I seem to rememeber the alt attribute on img does the same.

Answer (score 0):

If your html snippet appends the document dynamically, you should bind the click events of images . Hope this helps

```
$("body").on("click",".emoji-items img",function(){
$(".emoji-menu").fadeOut();
})
```

Comment: This example, html is your code and javascript is my answer and works like charm, did you include jQuery to your page or project?    https://jsfiddle.net/1d9rxwxr/

Comment: yes i'm using jQuery, I saw your fiddel but on my page this code is appending dynamically. please help, how I can fix this.

Comment: Can you show how you append this code or can you share the full page?

Comment: <div class="form-group" emoji-form emoji-message="emojiMessage">
    <label for="comment">Message:</label>
   <textarea placeholder="Enter a message..." id="messageInput" style="margin: 0 !important;resize: none;height: 95px;" class="form-control" rows="5"  ng-model="messageText" name="content" required>   </textarea>
<i id="emojibtn" class="fa fa-smile-o" style='float: right;'></i>
 <br>
 </div>   and the library i'm using is https://github.com/Coraza/angular-emoji-popup

Comment: When you enter message and emoji, the code you mentioned on top is appent right? Or can you show an example after entering message , what code is appent?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/95787/discussion-between-m-melih-and-sparsh-pipley).